# How to target parent product category and its children using WooCommerce?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic

In WooCommerce, archive-product is the default template for all product categories. I want to create a new product category template for one parent category and all of its children.

I've created a new template **archive-foo.php**

Now I need to change the code inside **taxonomy-product_cat.php** and tell it to use archive-foo.php "if it's my parent category or any of its children".

Here is my code inside **taxonomy-product_cat.php**:

```
if (is_product_category( 'foo-category' ) || cat_is_ancestor_of(19, get_queried_object()->term_id )){ wc_get_template( 'archive-foo.php' );
    } else { wc_get_template( 'archive-product.php' ); }
```

Currently, it's working for the parent category, but none of its children. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the WordPress function [`cat_is_ancestor_of()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/cat_is_ancestor_of/) is made for WordPress categories, **but not** for WooCommerce product categories which is a custom taxonomy `product_cat`.

For Custom taxonomies you can use WordPress [`term_is_ancestor_of()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/term_is_ancestor_of/) function like:

```
term_is_ancestor_of( 19, get_queried_object_id(), 'product_cat' )
```

So in your code:

```
if ( is_product_category( 'foo-category' ) || term_is_ancestor_of( 19, get_queried_object_id(), 'product_cat' ) ) { 
    wc_get_template( 'archive-foo.php' );
} else { 
    wc_get_template( 'archive-product.php' ); 
}
```

This time it should work.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you very much for taking the time to help!